# How to Send Message use Firebase Push Notification PHP MYSQL to All Tokens

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to do it in such a way when I use {select token FROM devices} it selects all tokens and sends push notifications to all of them but when I do it notifications are sent 2x but to the first data token on database.

```
<form method="post" action="send_notification.php">
Title<input type="text" name="title">
Message<input type="text" name="message">
<!--Icon path<input type="text" name="icon">-->
Token<input type="text" name="token">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send notification">
</form>

<?php

function sendNotification(){
include("../config/con.php");
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT token FROM devices");
$query_res = mysqli_fetch_array($query);


foreach ($query_res as $val) {
    $registrationIds[]=$val;
  }
    $url ="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    $fields=array(
        // "to"=>$_REQUEST['token'],
        "registration_ids"=>$registrationIds,
        "notification"=>array(
            "body"=>$_REQUEST['message'],
            "title"=>$_REQUEST['title'],
            // "icon"=>$_REQUEST['icon'],
            "click_action"=>"https://google.com/"
        )
    );

    $headers=array(
        'Authorization: key=key',
        'Content-Type:application/json'
    );

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fields));
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($result);
    curl_close($ch);
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    sendNotification();
}
```

Comment: {"multicast_id":1528735584925427843,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"4e2ece05-5e13-4cc2-96f8-a21300f41c86"},{"message_id":"ff89d441-8218-4199-a4a6-99e1d0de9a6c"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve it by trying this method:

Looping through the result set and retrieving all the tokens. Here's an updated snippet of the code:

```
// Retrieve all tokens from the database
$query_res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT token FROM devices");
$registrationIds = [];

// Iterate over each row and collect the tokens
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_res)) {
    $registrationIds[] = $row['token'];
}
```

In the revised code snippet, we have used mysqli_fetch_assoc() to fetch each row as an associative array. By employing a while loop, we can iterate over all the rows in the result set and extract the token value from each row. These token values are then added to the $registrationIds array.

This approach ensures that you have all the tokens from the database stored in the $registrationIds array. Consequently, the push notification will be sent to each token without any duplication.

Correct me if im wrong